# how to get previous and next dates in textbox

Tags: javascript, html

I have one textbox and two buttons.

- `button1` name as `prev`,
- `button2` name as `next`.
- `textbox` contains `current date`.

> ```
> If I click in next button the textbox will show the next date.
> If I click in prev button the textbox will show the previous date.
> ```

Please help me...

```
enter code here
<input type="text" id="txtDateFilter" readonly="readonly" runat="server" />

<div id="sfprevbtn" title="Prev" class="fbutton">
    <span class="fprev"></span>
</div>
<div id="sfnextbtn" title="Next" class="fbutton">
    <span class="fnext"></span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#sfprevbtn').click(function(e)
{
    $('#txtDateFilter').val();
});

$('#sfnextbtn').click(function(e)
{
    $('#txtDateFilter').val();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Have you got any code so far?

Comment: There is certainly a way to do so, can you show us what you wrote so far?

Comment: I had edited my code but how to get the previous date and next date on button click

Comment: @dannrob - Please don't link people to w3schools :) It's information is often misleading and miss-informative.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this fiddle I made: http://jsfiddle.net/TV57Q/

I made use of the Date object of javascript itself.

```
var date = new Date();
$(function () {
    // This writes out the current date to the text field as starter
    $('#field').val(date.toLocaleDateString());

    // Hook up previous button event
    $('#prev').click(function () {
        // Set our current date to 1 day earlier
        date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
        // Write the result to our text input
        $('#field').val(date.toLocaleDateString())
    });
    // Hook up next button event
    $('#next').click(function () {
        // Set our current date to 1 day later
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
        // Write the result to our text input
        $('#field').val(date.toLocaleDateString())
    });
});
```